# What am I doing wrong? -php newbie

Tags: php

We were able to run it in our comp lab a while ago, but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or something's missing on my desktop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="sample2.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then we used this to print the input on a different page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];
echo $name;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to actually _explain_ what's not working instead of just saying "it doesn't work". Nobody can help you solve your problem if you don't give more details

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please improve your question by posting all relevant **error messages** exactly as they appear. Also, make sure to include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? What is actually wrong?

Comment: Dont downvote the question, he is new, just explain like the above, what he needs to do to make it better

Comment: Don't upvote the question, he's new, and this will teach him not to ask good questions because asking bad ones gives positive reputation.

Comment: Are you running an `Apache` serever in your machine?

Comment: The second code block ("the different page") ... is it in file `sample2.php`?

Comment: @RyanMurphy the question needs clarification and show efforts, no matter how emphatic people could be. FAQs are there for a reason, after all, not reading them doesn't make you immune from following them

Comment: I'm sorry.
I was trying to print the exact input from the first page. This is a copy-paste of what we coded a while ago, I do not know what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a webserver like XAMPP on your desktop and open the HTML using localhost://form.html for example

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

You should use the `XAMPP Portable Lite` version which has all you need but not too much

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems perfect. but may be the problem is that you are not running the code on server like Apache..

Follow this step..

1) Install `XAMPP` (you can download xampp from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/))

XAMPP, available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp, is an open source installer that will install Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl, phpMyAdmin, and an FTP server. It is suitable for Linux, Solaris, and Windows systems

2) Go to XAMPP > htdocs > create folder (project)

3) in project folder create 2 files

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="sample2.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**sample2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];
echo $name;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

4) run code :- `http://localhost/project`

Comment: This might be the solution! I believe this is what I'm missing. I'll try it now. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, can someone briefly explain how XAMPP would know which file should be opened first given http://localhost/project?

Comment: IN the file apache/conf/httpd.conf is this text which tells apache to look first for an index.php and load it. if this does not exist then search for index.pl and load it. if this does not exist ... #
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
...

Comment: Please add comment before down voting...

Comment: @user2836881 XAMPP is a LAMP tool, it will install php, mysql and in your pc. and you can run the php code through it.

Comment: I think he has understood what XAMPP is but just wanted to know if Apache takes index.html or index.php or more precisely how Apache/XAMPP knows which file to load (DirectoryIndey, just a simple try and error search)